# Vagrant - how to print Chef's command output to stdout?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, cookbook

If we have in Chef cookbook code like:

```
if !File.exists?('/vagrant/project/target/project/WEB-INF") || node[:compile_project]
  bash "build project" do
    user "vagrant"
    cwd "/vagrant/project"
    code <<-EOH
      mvn clean
      mvn db-migration:migrate
      mvn package
    EOH
  end
end
```

When run `vagrant up` we can see only brief information that 'build project' is executed.

However wen we run 'mvn package' command from terminal we can see full command output. **How to tell Vagrant/Chef to show full output?**

*EDIT:*

I've tried this but nothing has changed in output.

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.log_level = :debug
```

Comment: Okay, I think the answer is no. If the script works, the output stays hidden. However, one (extremely) hacky way to do this might be add attributes `returns 2` and `ignore_failure`, which would fail every time. You get full output on failure. I would only use this technique to debug, however. And submit a feature request to opscode.

Comment: Have you tried using the "flags" option for the bash resource to pass '-x' ?

Answer (score 3):

I know nothing about vagrant but I think this may relate to your issue... Happy to delete this answer if proves to be irrelevant!

> [--force-formatter](http://docs.opscode.com/ctl_chef_solo.html)
>
> Indicates that formatter output will be used instead of logger output.

So I found if `solo.rb` has `log_location` defined adding the option `--force-formatter` displays the output when running chef via rundeck or remotely executing `ssh user@host "chef-solo --force-formatter"`

Comment: Thanks for the tip here, I managed to get vagrant to output the full chef run's output with `chef.arguments = '--force-formatter'` in the chef part of the Vagrantfile!

Answer (score 2):

It prints bash/script/execute resource execution output to stdout only when:

- You need **TTY** for your remote chef-solo/chef-client command.
- not run chef-client in daemon mode
- chef log level is set to `:debug`

See the [code `chef/Mixin/ShellOut`, line 36](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb#L36).

When using `vagrant up`, it seems no option to provide a TTY for the ssh session, so the solution is kind of walk around after you set `:debug` log level for chef:

1. run `$ vagrant up`
2. run `$ vagrant ssh -- -t` - which means it passes `-t` to ssh command so that there's a tty for the ssh session.
3. run `chef-solo` to manually run chef, then you will get output on stdout.