# How can I set the log output level for Chef on Amazon OpsWorks?

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks

My question is similar to: [How can I display the output of a Opscode Chef bash command in my console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813592/how-can-i-display-the-output-of-a-opscode-chef-bash-command-in-my-console)

I want to be able to see console output for my running recipe. In particular, my recipe failed to start JBoss because `JAVA_HOME` was not being set. It took me an entire day to figure this out because the statement `JAVA_HOME is undefined` was not being printed to the Chef output. When running chef solo, debugging output can be turned on by appending `-l debug` to the command, as in: `chef-solo -c solo.rb -j node.json -l debug`

However, when using Amazon OpsWorks, there is no such option:

```
sudo opsworks-agent-cli run_command [activity] [date] [/path/to/valid/json.file]
```

How can I add a log level to `run_command`?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running:

```
cd /opt/aws/opsworks/current
bundle exec chef-solo -l debug -c conf/solo.rb -j /var/lib/aws/opsworks/chef/XXX.json
```

Answer (score 9):

source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/troubleshoot.html

Each Chef run produces a log, which provides a detailed description of the run and is a valuable troubleshooting resource. To specify the amount of detail in the log, add a Chef::Log.level statement to a custom recipe that specifies the desired log level. The default value is :info. The following example shows how to set the Chef log level to :debug, which provides the most detailed description of the run.

```
Chef::Log.level = :debug
```

In your recipe, add the following

```
require 'chef/log'
Chef::Log.level = :debug
...
```

You can also control the log using the custom_json property in stack setting.

```
{"opsworks":{"chef_log_level":"debug"}}
```

The above turns on debug for chef and opsworks, but does not yet show the output of the commands you might run using bash or other script.