# Chef: obtain value from remote command

Tags: chef-infra

I am using a cookbook to randomly generate GPG keys for users (e.g. in this case duplicity) I need to be able to use the value of the public key ID when I run (e.g. when you run gpg --list-keys) in my chef recipe. I need to use the ID in the following command:

`PASSPHRASE=\"\" duplicity full --encrypt-key=\"[ID]\" [SRC] rsync://[USER]@[SERVER].[FQDN].[tld]:#{hostname}/`

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display the output of a Opscode Chef bash command in my console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813592/how-can-i-display-the-output-of-a-opscode-chef-bash-command-in-my-console)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is almost answered here: [How can I display the output of a Opscode Chef bash command in my console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813592/how-can-i-display-the-output-of-a-opscode-chef-bash-command-in-my-console)

In the `ruby_block`, you can do whatever you want with the output.