# chef-solo getting logs from a bash script

Tags: ruby, chef-solo

I am executing a shell script via chef like below

```
execute 'Run postgres data migration' do
  command '/home/ubuntu/build-target/infra-base/psql10_migration.sh'
  live_stream true
  action  :run
  only_if { ::File.exist?('/home/ubuntu/build-target/infra-base/psql10_migration.sh') }
end
```

My chef logs are directed to a file (`log_location '/var/log/arkin/chef-run.log'` )

Right now I am not getting any logs from the bash script `psql10_migration.sh`. Can someone let me know how can I get the logs from the bash script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used in bash redirection like below

```
execute 'Run postgres data migration' do
  command '/home/ubuntu/build-target/infra-base/psql10_migration.sh >> /home/ubuntu/logs/psql10-migration.log 2>&1'
  action  :run
  only_if { ::File.exist?('/home/ubuntu/build-target/infra-base/psql10_migration.sh') }
end
```